# How to disallow special characters in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, validation, awt

I am trying to disallow special characters in `JTextField`. This is for a project where I need to do form validation. At the moment I can only allow numbers but I cannot disallow special characters such as `@` or `#` or `/` or `\`. Below is what I have made so far.

```java
private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    try {
        int i= Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter Int Value", "Invail Input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression to validate the field?

Comment: Is this what you want https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-can-we-make-jtextfield-accept-only-numbers-in-java

Comment: You should use either [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) or [InputVerifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) for this. Or perhaps a [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) would suffice?

Answer (score 2):

I think, instead of adding listeners and using just a simple `JTextField`, you can use `JFormattedTextField`. As it is said in Oracle docs:

> JFormattedTextField - A JTextField subclass that allows you to specify the legal set of characters that the user can enter.

Check the links below:

- [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)
- [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#format)

Comment: I think you may include in your answer a regex to be used with the AbstractFormatter of the JFormattedTextField if you can. Anyway +1. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that uses `InputVerifier`. It is a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so you can copy the code as is and run it. Note that class `InputVerifier` was modified in JDK 9. Nonetheless the below code should work with any JDK version.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.InputVerifier;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class InpVerif implements Runnable {
    private JFrame frame;

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        createAndDisplayGui();
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Input Verifier");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets.bottom = 5;
        gbc.insets.left = 5;
        gbc.insets.right = 5;
        gbc.insets.top = 5;
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter Text");
        mainPanel.add(label, gbc);
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        textField.setInputVerifier(new SpecialCharactersVerifier());
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        mainPanel.add(textField, gbc);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Disallowed Characters");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        mainPanel.add(label2, gbc);
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField("@ # / \\");
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        mainPanel.add(textField2, gbc);
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private class SpecialCharactersVerifier extends InputVerifier {
        private String regex = "^.*[@#/\\\\].*$";

        @Override
        public boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input) {
            boolean verified = verify(input);
            if (!verified) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                              "These characters not allowed: @ # / \\",
                                              "ERROR: Illegal Character[s]",
                                              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            return verified;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            boolean verified = true;
            if (input instanceof JTextComponent) {
                JTextComponent textComponent = (JTextComponent) input;
                String text = textComponent.getText();
                if (text != null) {
                    verified = !text.matches(regex);
                }
            }
            return verified;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new InpVerif());
    }
}
```

Note that *JavaFX* is [supposedly] the successor to *Swing*, so if you are considering new GUI development in java, perhaps you should consider using *JavaFX*. If you must use *Swing*, I highly recommend [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Entering numeric values JTextField :

you can use addKeyListener : keyPressed

```
jTextField2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
        String value = jTextField2.getText();
        int len = value.length();
        if (k.getKeyChar() >= '0' && k.getKeyChar() <= '9') {
           jTextField2.setEditable(true);
        } else {
           jTextField2.setEditable(false);
        }
     }
  });
```

Comment: How can do this with characters like @*# for example

Comment: sorry what I wrote about isn't clear I'm looking a format expectation which doesn't all special characters

Comment: Will a `KeyListener` work if I paste text into a `JTextField`?

Comment: `KeyListener` is the wrong tool for this job. It is a very low level listener. Either an `InputVerifier` as seen in [@Abra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59686862/418556) or a `JFormattedTextField` as in [Armine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59680219/418556) is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```java
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
 String value = tf.getText();
 if (ke.getKeyChar() != '@' && ke.getKeyChar() != '#' && ke.getKeyChar() != '/' 
 && ke.getKeyChar() != '\') {
     tf.setEditable(true);
 } else {
     tf.setEditable(false);
     label.setText("Please enter Int Value, Invail Input");
 }
}
```

Comment: what does the ke. mean??? I've not seen this before, i'm still learning java

Comment: @KevinMedjiako I missed to copy function. My bad. Check the edit.

Comment: @Kevin Medjiako ke is an Object of type KeyEvent. KeyEvent gets generated by the component once a key is pressed.

Comment: `KeyListener` is the wrong tool for this job. It is a very low level listener. Either an `InputVerifier` as seen in [Abra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59686862/418556) or a `JFormattedTextField` as in [Armine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59680219/418556) is the way to go here.